# Does fasttext use deep learning model?

Tags: python, fasttext

I nearly study library fasttext to classification text. I would like is know if fasttext is using deep learning model, specifically CNN to. A senior python who used fasttext to classify text told me that fasttext uses CNN model but I did not find this online.
Please,help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Check out https://ai.stackexchange.com/ for a better home for this question, which is not really in scope for StackOverflow!
Short answer, no, fasttext is shallow, and no convolutional layers are used AFAIK https://towardsdatascience.com/fasttext-bag-of-tricks-for-efficient-text-classification-513ba9e302e7?gi=b9673069346a

Comment: short answer: yes, long answer: read the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01759.pdf

Comment: short answer: no CNN, no deep learning, but shallow neural network. The paper is clearer and detailed.

Comment: Anakin87: thank you so much

Comment: If my comment was useful, please upvote it.